# cakephp 3 installation issue - unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in config/bootstrap.php on line 107

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have php 5.4.42 on Linux with Apache and mysql. All the required extensions are loaded and I did a fresh install of cakephp 3 using the command
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app c3

It installed everything but when I open the URL in browser, it shows me an error in the browser
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in c3/config/bootstrap.php on line 107

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution from cakephp github. My php version is not correct. Issue is that command line on linux (php -v) shows version as 5.4.42 but correct version is shown only using phpinfo() on a webpage and there it shows 5.3.29